# unable to reset input field -- (input filed is used by plugin selectize)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, selectize.js, angularjs-3rd-party

This is my html code: this is my input filed where i have declare input type and id.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
   <div class="form-group">
      <div>
         <input id="SkillsAndInterests" class="form-control" type="text" 
                name="SkillsAndInterests" style="width:286px;height:35px;" />
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

This is my js code :

```
vm.CommunityMembersAdditionalInfoData.SkillsAndInterests = vm.skillsandinterestarray;
$('#SkillsAndInterests').tagSuggest({
    data: vm.CommunityMembersAdditionalInfoData.SkillsAndInterests,
    sortOrder: 'name',
    maxDropHeight: 200,
    name: 'SkillsAndInterests'
});
```

And this is my reset function: where i am unable reset filed

```
vm.ResetSerachMembers = function () {
    $("#SkillsAndInterests").val('');
}
```

And this is my button where i am calling reset function:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="data.isMembersLoading"
        ng-click="data.ResetSerachMembers();" type="button">
  Reset
</button>
```

Comment: Mixing AngularJS and jQuery like this is asking for trouble. Consider using a third party library such as [angular-selectizejs](https://github.com/danielqa/angular-selectizejs).

Comment: can anyone help me out from this

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).